# Is there a way to save the weights and load them on another file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So, is simple as the title of the question, is there a way to save the weights after training like this

```
model.save_weights("path")
```

and then load them on another project only with

```
model = load_weights("path")
model.predict(x)
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

yes. it is possible if you call the right path

for instance, you have this path

```
- project1/cool.py
- project2/another_cool.py
```

you train with cool.py and the model is saved inside project1's folder. then you want to load the model in another_cool.py

just call `load_model` function with path `../project1/weigh.h5`

Comment: but how can I do that?

Comment: and if I do that I can predict? even if I don't have the model in that file?

Comment: yes. you can predict with a loaded trained model. after you load the model, you can use the model to predict

Comment: you cannot call the file that doesn't exist. so you still need the model file

Comment: is giving me this error PermissionError: [Errno 13] Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'D:\DOT\Speechrecognition\SpeechWeights', errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

Comment: whne I try to load the weights

Comment: I don't know what's causing that error happens because the reason that happens varies. usually, that error happens because the file is being used by another program or your program literally don't have permission to access the file

Comment: try to close another program that might use the file and load it on your program.

Comment: if that is not solving your problem, try to give permission to the file. 

if any of that is not working, I don't know any other solution

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to save/load the weights, you can use

`model.save_weights("path/to/my_model_weights.hdf5")`

and then to reload (potentially in another python project / in another interpreter, you just have to update the path accordingly)

`other_model.load_weights("path/to/my_model_weights.hdf5")`

However both models should have the same architecture (instances of the same class), and Python/tensorflow/keras versions should be the same. See [the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#saving_loading_only_the_models_weights_values) for more info.

You can save both weights and architecture through `model.save("path/to/my_model.hdf5")`for saving on disk and `keras.models.load_model("path/to/my_model.hdf5")`for loading from disk (once again, [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) should provide details).

Once loaded in memory, you can retrain your model, or use predict on it, predictions should be identical between projects

Answer (score 0):

Assume the model-weight's name is model.h5

Save model weights in another folder:

```
model.save_weights("/model/"+model.h5)
```

Load model weights in another folder:

```
model.load_weights("/model/"+model.h5)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).